# Continuity errors about Rick's hand in The Walking Dead comic

Tags: comics, the-walking-dead

As fans of the comics know, in the *The Walking Dead* comic books,

> The governor cut off Rick's hand.  Apparently, the artists sometimes forget this, and in multiple cases, they have supposedly drawn him with two hands after the run in with the governor.

I haven't seen any such images myself, despite having looked for them.

**Do they exist?  If so, can you find a few instances of this continuity error, including issue numbers, and provide images of at least some of them?**

Comment: Note:  There will be a bounty for a particularly good answer.

Comment: I think a better question would be if they actually exist

Comment: @TomSterkenburg - I'm pretty sure they do, but it will make the question less likely to attract downvotes, so I edited.

Comment: It seems like a fine question to me. Maybe perhaps asking for a list, but other than that, pretty solid.

Comment: I'm up by 4 points, so it doesn't matter much, and in any case, I have enough rep to spare a few points.

Comment: I'll admit that I started out thinking it was a list question (even asked as much in chat), but I was not among the downvoters.

Comment: *Finite* list questions are ok, I think...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page](https://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Issue_123), Issue 123:

> Even though Rick had his right hand amputated by The Governor in #28, he is seen shooting with his right hand in a panel on page 21.

[image: Rick on far right]

Further cases from [this page](http://www.thespoilingdeadfans.com/threads/list-of-errors-and-goofs-in-the-comics.8968/):

> ISSUE 48
>
> Even though Rick had his right hand amputated by The Governor in #28, he is seen with both of his hands when hugging his family in this issue.

[image: Rick's hand visible on her shoulder]

> ISSUE 49
>
> Even though Rick had his right hand amputated by The Governor in #28, he is seen with both of his hands when he closes the door of the bathroom.

[image: Rick against closed door with both hands.]

> ISSUE 54
>
> Even though Rick had his right hand amputated by The Governor in #28, when walking with Carl in the issue, his left hand is missing instead.
>
> [image]
>
> ISSUE 59
>
> Even though Rick had his right hand amputated by The Governor in #28, there is a panel in this issue which shows Rick with both of his hands while holding Carl, after getting out of the car in the middle of the herd attack.

This one I couldn't find, but I suspect that it might be someone confused over this panel, which has both of Carl's arms around Rick's stub:

[image]

> ISSUE 61
>
> Even though Rick had his right hand amputated by The Governor in #28, he is seen holding the telephone with his right hand in one panel.

[image: Rick picking up phone]

> ISSUE 69
>
> Even though Rick had his right hand amputated by The Governor in #28, he is seen with both of his hands when he's talking with Abraham about the Alexandria Safe-Zone.

[image: Rick talking to Abraham]

> ISSUE 72
>
> Even though Rick had his right hand amputated by The Governor in #28, he is seen holding Carl's shoulder while leaving the house.

[image: Rick with hand on Carl's shoulder]

> ISSUE 97
>
> Even though Rick had his right hand amputated by The Governor in #28, there is a panel in this issue which shows Rick with both of his hands when talking with Andrea.

[image: Rick talking to Andrea]

As well as further evidence from the [continuity errors section of Rick's page](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Rick_Grimes_(Comic_Series)#Continuity_Error.28s.29) on the Wikia:

On the Compendium Volume 3, Barnes & Noble Variant cover:

[image: Compendium Three Barnes & Noble Variant cover]

> ISSUE 185
>
> When visiting Dwight in a holding cell.

[image: Rick visits Dwight in prison]

Comment: Honestly, I think they're confused in Issue 59.

Comment: I actually had the same thought about issue 59, but I wasn't sure.  That's certainly the only panel that could conceivably be misconstrued as depicting Rick with two hands.

Comment: Bounty tomorrow, by the way.

Comment: 11 hours remaining before I can open a bounty.

Comment: I've been there before.

Comment: :) *poke* I'm not hurting for rep, but I figured I'd remind you of the bounty.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit. To be honest, I left out the issue #168 one because I reckon [this panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSti4.png) could be just a game of shadows, and his right hand is indeed the stub one.